Update the text of a Kotlin text field
I make an async request, and after i completes, how do I update the status_text a the bottom of this example?
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = async {

                try {
                    val url = URL(getString(R.string.api_endpoint))
                    val urlConnection = url.openConnection()
                    val inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()
                    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))

                    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
                    var line: String?
                    while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line)

                    }

                    reader.close()
                    inputStream.close()

                    val jsonString = stringBuilder.toString()

                    val gson = Gson()
                    val data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Pondus::class.java)

                    data
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG exception", e.toString())
                }

            }.await()


            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                setContent {
                    PondusTheme {
                        InputValues(response)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun InputValues(result: Any) {

        var statusText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        Column {
            Row {
                TextField(
                    value = statusText,
                    onValueChange = { statusText = it },
                )
            }
            Row {
                MakeButton()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun MakeButton() {

        Button(onClick = { sendValue(23.4F) }) {
            Text(text = "Some text goes here")
        }
    }

    private fun sendValue(value: Float): Boolean {

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = async {
                // Perform network operation here

                val client = HttpClient()
                val response: HttpResponse =
                    client.post(getString(R.string.api_endpoint_2)) {
                        setBody("Body content")
                    }
            }.await()

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {

                // Update status_text here <--
            }
        }
        return true
    }


}


This is some text that I have written so that I can submit the example. You don't have to read it. This is some text that I have written so that I can submit the example. You don't have to read it.

Where is the Button, where is the TextField? What is statusText and why is the Row so important? Please add a [mre] so we can get the whole picture.

It seems you're used to XML, in Compose we do things a bit differently, you do not reference the view itself, but the values it uses and it will
react automatically (or at least it should, if done correctly):
// remember makes sure the value survives recompositions
// mutableStateOf makes compose "observe it" and react when it changes
// this will hold the text that's inside of the textField itself
var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

Row(
   modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(start = 12.dp, top = 5.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
) {
          TextField(
                value = textFieldValue, // reacts when textFieldValue gets changed
                onValueChange = { textFieldValue = it }, // when value changes assign to our textFieldValue, which will make the TextField react
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                   fontSize = 17.sp,
                   fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif
                )
          )
          
          // on click here updates our value that compose observes, and makes it recompose the textField
          Button(onClick = {textFieldValue = "hello :)"}) {
              Text("Update text field")
          }
}

also, this does require a fair amount of imports, just bear that in mind

Thanks. The textFieldValue in my example isn't updated in the same function. When I click the button, data is sent to a server. When the response comes back (async) I want to update the text. But the textFieldValue isn't in that scope.

you can always keep the value in some view model (in a stateFlow), collect it in the composable (.collectAsState()) and emit to it whenever the user edits the text field (in onValueChange call a viewModel function to emit a new value) and use the same stateFlow in the function to emit whatever your backend responds with

update your question with more code and I shall edit my post accordingly :)

I will update it as soon as have a moment :-)
